# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: angular, laravel-5

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjPhZ.png)

I am getting this error in my angular project I am using angular version 6 and laravel 5

```
export class ServicesService {
    baseUrl = 'https://savuk.000webhostapp.com/public/api/';
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authentication:  ) {
    }
    getcountries() {
        console.log(this.authentication.gettocken());


        return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + 'country/all', {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ')
        });
    }
}
```

this is the service from which api is called

Comment: Please provide more information and if necessary more code

Comment: I am calling an api to get some information the api require jwt authorisation and it needs token to be added in the header the api works fine when header is not added but when ever authorisation header is added the api will make  an error response the screenshot of error response is added in the question

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to resolve this issue when I had it,

Enter the below url in you chrome browser

```
 chrome://net-internals/#sockets
```

Click on `Sockets`  and then `Flush Socket pools`